# How to automatically convert CSV file to XLS file with filters and formatting of the top row?

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion, csv

I have a big CSV file (10,000s of rows).

How can I automatically convert it to an XLS file which will have Filters and some formatting (color, font) on the top row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this with an .xls template file and some scripting to move the data from the CSV.          - create an xls file with the properlyu formatted top row
- When you need to"convert the file, in your script, make a copy of the template then open it for editing
- iterate through the csv file allthe while copying the data to a new row in the xls file

Excel has a COM programming interface that can facilitate this.